# Snowflake vs Spark - Insufficient privileges to operate on schema

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've created a new free standard snowflake account "xxxxx" I was able to access the default database, schema, and the tables from Snowflake web UI.

And tried connecting to Snowflake from Spark

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[1]")
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
    .getOrCreate();

  var sfOptions = Map(
    "sfURL" -> "https://xxxxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/",
    "sfAccount" -> "xxxxxx",
    "sfUser" -> "xxxxx",
    "sfPassword" -> "#########",
    "sfDatabase" -> "snowflake_sample_data",
    "sfSchema" -> "tpch_sf1"
  )
  val df: DataFrame = spark.read
    .format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake")
    .options(sfOptions)
    .option("query", "SELECT l_returnflag,l_linestatus,sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty FROM lineitem GROUP BY l_returnflag,l_linestatus")
    .load()
```

After running, getting "Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'TPCH_SF1' " error. Could someone please help.

20/02/23 19:35:12 WARN SnowflakeStrategy: Pushdown failed :SQL access control error:
Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'TPCH_SF1'
20/02/23 19:35:13 INFO SnowflakeSQLStatement: Spark Connector Master: execute query with bind variable: create  temporary stage if not exists identifier(?) 
20/02/23 19:35:13 WARN SnowflakeStrategy: Pushdown failed :SQL access control error:
Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'TPCH_SF1'
20/02/23 19:35:14 INFO SnowflakeSQLStatement: Spark Connector Master: execute query with bind variable: create  temporary stage if not exists identifier(?) 
Exception in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL access control error:
Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'TPCH_SF1'
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowExceptionSub(SnowflakeUtil.java:152)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:77)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.pollForOutput(StmtUtil.java:495)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:372)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:575)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQueryInternal(SFStatement.java:265)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:203)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:874)

Comment: When you connect to Snowflake Console, can you see `snowflake_sample_data`  database (on the left part when you are on Worksheets) with your default role?

Comment: Yes, I can see and run the same query and got the result back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with Spark connector, you need CREATE STAGE privileges on schema you use. Instead of using tpch_sf1 schema, use a schema that you have privileges to create stage and use fully qualified name of the table (database, schema, table name):

```
  var sfOptions = Map(
    "sfURL" -> "https://xxxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/",
    "sfAccount" -> "xxxxx",
    "sfUser" -> "xxxxx",
    "sfPassword" -> "#########",
    "sfDatabase" -> "your_own_database",
    "sfSchema" -> "your_own_Schema"
  )


  val df: DataFrame = spark.read
    .format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake")
    .options(sfOptions)
    .option("query", "SELECT l_returnflag,l_linestatus,sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty FROM snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.lineitem GROUP BY l_returnflag,l_linestatus")
    .load()
```

Comment: Thanks, Atil. Snowflake is by default giving us the default database, hence thought of using it and accessing from Spark. It's strange, not able to access it, maybe snowflake should consider this for their future releases. By creating a new database and table, I am able to access from Spark

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a view on top of shared database tables, in the schema where you have access, then query the view:

```
CREATE VIEW PUBLIC.TPCH_SF10_REGION 
AS 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF10"."REGION"
```